# Core Plugin in QtCreator5?

Tags: qt, plugins

Im a beginner at **Qt**, and i write a program that need **`Core::ActionManager`**.
Now in **QtCreator** that i downloaded (`5.3.2 Version`), there is no **Core** plugin, just a **QtCore** that hasn't **ActionManager**.
I searched everywhere but i couldn't find how **install & use Core**.
Can someone please tell me how i have to install it?!
Thank you a lot and sorry for my poor english.

Comment: There is no such thing as an `ActionManager` in Qt.  How do you know that you need it?

Comment: There is no `ActionManager`, but there is `Core::ActionManager` and could define shortcuts and actions. after a lot of searches i found it, but dont know how can i work with it, because some of parameters! so if someone could help me, i appreciated.

Comment: No there isn't. `Core::ActionManager` is a part of Qt Creator's API *not* Qt's.  So have you downloaded Qt Creator's API? http://qt-project.org/downloads

Comment: I have QtCreator IDE and work with it. in this IDE i can't work with `Core::ActionManager`. the core plugin was in another place and now it works! but in using `Core::ActionManager` i dont know what parameter i have to use, because some of it like `Id ID` i don't know what i have to input! and if you know anything about it, i hope you help me. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As cmannett85 said, Core::ActionManager is part of Qt Creator's own API. It is only relevant when you want to modify Qt Creator itself. It is not relevant if you want to develop an application using the Qt libraries.

Comment: thanks, so is there something like `RegisterHotKey()` in Visual for Qt?